# where clause requiring double quotes on an nvarchar?

Tags: double, quotes, nvarchar

all columns in DataImport table are `nvarchar(max)`. column d is requiring double quotes.

the statement:

```
select cast(i.a as varchar(50)) as address,cast(i.c as varchar(50)) as phone
    from dataimport i where i.d="x"
```

produces two records.

the statement:

```
select cast(i.a as varchar(50)) as address,cast(i.c as varchar(50)) as phone
from dataimport i where i.d='x'
```

produces no records

```
column definition is d(nvarchar(max),null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a column called x?

Using double quotes you're specifying column names and not data inside a column.

If the statement is not returning any data using single quotes there seems to be no record containing a 'x' inside column d.

Comment: The column name is d and the value in the table(dataimportnew i) being sought is 'X' so the query reads  "where i.d="X". It should have returned nothing. I have since added i.d to the result set and it comes up with 'A'. It's getting more bizarre.